# G++ not understanding console option

Tags: c++, gcc, g++, glfw

So, I need to compile, assemble, and link a C++ file. But, I need to use an external library with it. So, I'm attempting to do so with G++ using this batch file:

```
g++ -c WindowTest.cpp -I include\bgfx-master\include\bgfx -I include\glfw-3.3.8.bin.WIN32\include\GLFW --verbose
g++ WindowTest.o -o WindowTest.exe -static -L include\glfw-3.3.8.bin.WIN32\lib-vc2022 -l glfw3.lib --verbose
```

However, when run, I get this output:

```
g++ -c WindowTest.cpp -I include\bgfx-master\include\bgfx -I include\glfw-3.3.8.bin.WIN32\include\GLFW --verbose
Using built-in specs.
COLLECT_GCC=g++
Target: mingw32
Configured with: ../src/gcc-6.3.0/configure --build=x86_64-pc-linux-gnu --host=mingw32 --with-gmp=/mingw --with-mpfr=/mingw --with-mpc=/mingw --with-isl=/mingw --prefix=/mingw --disable-win32-registry --target=mingw32 --with-arch=i586 --enable-languages=c,c++,objc,obj-c++,fortran,ada --with-pkgversion='MinGW.org GCC-6.3.0-1' --enable-static --enable-shared --enable-threads --with-dwarf2 --disable-sjlj-exceptions --enable-version-specific-runtime-libs --with-libiconv-prefix=/mingw --with-libintl-prefix=/mingw --enable-libstdcxx-debug --with-tune=generic --enable-libgomp --disable-libvtv --enable-nls
Thread model: win32
gcc version 6.3.0 (MinGW.org GCC-6.3.0-1)
COLLECT_GCC_OPTIONS='-c' '-I' 'include\bgfx-master\include\bgfx' '-I' 'include\glfw-3.3.8.bin.WIN32\include\GLFW' '-v' '-shared-libgcc' '-mtune=generic' '-march=i586'
 c:/mingw/bin/../libexec/gcc/mingw32/6.3.0/cc1plus.exe -quiet -v -I include\bgfx-master\include\bgfx -I include\glfw-3.3.8.bin.WIN32\include\GLFW -iprefix c:\mingw\bin\../lib/gcc/mingw32/6.3.0/ WindowTest.cpp -quiet -dumpbase WindowTest.cpp -mtune=generic -march=i586 -auxbase WindowTest -version -o C:\Users\owenr\AppData\Local\Temp\ccnfsknd.s
GNU C++14 (MinGW.org GCC-6.3.0-1) version 6.3.0 (mingw32)
        compiled by GNU C version 6.3.0, GMP version 6.1.2, MPFR version 3.1.5, MPC version 1.0.2, isl version 0.15
warning: MPC header version 1.0.2 differs from library version 1.0.3.
GGC heuristics: --param ggc-min-expand=100 --param ggc-min-heapsize=131072
ignoring duplicate directory "c:/mingw/lib/gcc/../../lib/gcc/mingw32/6.3.0/include/c++"
ignoring duplicate directory "c:/mingw/lib/gcc/../../lib/gcc/mingw32/6.3.0/include/c++/mingw32" 
ignoring duplicate directory "c:/mingw/lib/gcc/../../lib/gcc/mingw32/6.3.0/include/c++/backward"
ignoring duplicate directory "c:/mingw/lib/gcc/../../lib/gcc/mingw32/6.3.0/include"
ignoring duplicate directory "/mingw/lib/gcc/mingw32/6.3.0/../../../../include"    
ignoring duplicate directory "c:/mingw/lib/gcc/../../include"
ignoring duplicate directory "c:/mingw/lib/gcc/../../lib/gcc/mingw32/6.3.0/include-fixed"
ignoring duplicate directory "c:/mingw/lib/gcc/../../lib/gcc/mingw32/6.3.0/../../../../mingw32/include"
ignoring duplicate directory "/mingw/include"
#include "..." search starts here:
#include <...> search starts here:
 include\bgfx-master\include\bgfx
 include\glfw-3.3.8.bin.WIN32\include\GLFW
 c:\mingw\bin\../lib/gcc/mingw32/6.3.0/include/c++
 c:\mingw\bin\../lib/gcc/mingw32/6.3.0/include/c++/mingw32
 c:\mingw\bin\../lib/gcc/mingw32/6.3.0/include/c++/backward
 c:\mingw\bin\../lib/gcc/mingw32/6.3.0/include
 c:\mingw\bin\../lib/gcc/mingw32/6.3.0/../../../../include
 c:\mingw\bin\../lib/gcc/mingw32/6.3.0/include-fixed
 c:\mingw\bin\../lib/gcc/mingw32/6.3.0/../../../../mingw32/include
End of search list.
GNU C++14 (MinGW.org GCC-6.3.0-1) version 6.3.0 (mingw32)
        compiled by GNU C version 6.3.0, GMP version 6.1.2, MPFR version 3.1.5, MPC version 1.0.2, isl version 0.15
warning: MPC header version 1.0.2 differs from library version 1.0.3.
GGC heuristics: --param ggc-min-expand=100 --param ggc-min-heapsize=131072
Compiler executable checksum: af09a87986453bf79da3565f33c7648f
COLLECT_GCC_OPTIONS='-c' '-I' 'include\bgfx-master\include\bgfx' '-I' 'include\glfw-3.3.8.bin.WIN32\include\GLFW' '-v' '-shared-libgcc' '-mtune=generic' '-march=i586'
 c:/mingw/bin/../lib/gcc/mingw32/6.3.0/../../../../mingw32/bin/as.exe -v -I include\bgfx-master\include\bgfx -I include\glfw-3.3.8.bin.WIN32\include\GLFW -o WindowTest.o C:\Users\owenr\AppData\Local\Temp\ccnfsknd.s
GNU assembler version 2.28 (mingw32) using BFD version (GNU Binutils) 2.28
COMPILER_PATH=c:/mingw/bin/../libexec/gcc/mingw32/6.3.0/;c:/mingw/bin/../libexec/gcc/;c:/mingw/bin/../lib/gcc/mingw32/6.3.0/../../../../mingw32/bin/
LIBRARY_PATH=c:/mingw/bin/../lib/gcc/mingw32/6.3.0/;c:/mingw/bin/../lib/gcc/;c:/mingw/bin/../lib/gcc/mingw32/6.3.0/../../../../mingw32/lib/;c:/mingw/bin/../lib/gcc/mingw32/6.3.0/../../../
COLLECT_GCC_OPTIONS='-c' '-I' 'include\bgfx-master\include\bgfx' '-I' 'include\glfw-3.3.8.bin.WIN32\include\GLFW' '-v' '-shared-libgcc' '-mtune=generic' '-march=i586'

$-> g++ WindowTest.o -o WindowTest.exe -static -L include\glfw-3.3.8.bin.WIN32\lib-vc2022 -l glfw3.lib --verbose
Using built-in specs.
COLLECT_GCC=g++
COLLECT_LTO_WRAPPER=c:/mingw/bin/../libexec/gcc/mingw32/6.3.0/lto-wrapper.exe
Target: mingw32
Configured with: ../src/gcc-6.3.0/configure --build=x86_64-pc-linux-gnu --host=mingw32 --with-gmp=/mingw --with-mpfr=/mingw --with-mpc=/mingw --with-isl=/mingw --prefix=/mingw --disable-win32-registry --target=mingw32 --with-arch=i586 --enable-languages=c,c++,objc,obj-c++,fortran,ada --with-pkgversion='MinGW.org GCC-6.3.0-1' --enable-static --enable-shared --enable-threads --with-dwarf2 --disable-sjlj-exceptions --enable-version-specific-runtime-libs --with-libiconv-prefix=/mingw --with-libintl-prefix=/mingw --enable-libstdcxx-debug --with-tune=generic --enable-libgomp --disable-libvtv --enable-nls
Thread model: win32
gcc version 6.3.0 (MinGW.org GCC-6.3.0-1) 
COMPILER_PATH=c:/mingw/bin/../libexec/gcc/mingw32/6.3.0/;c:/mingw/bin/../libexec/gcc/;c:/mingw/bin/../lib/gcc/mingw32/6.3.0/../../../../mingw32/bin/
LIBRARY_PATH=c:/mingw/bin/../lib/gcc/mingw32/6.3.0/;c:/mingw/bin/../lib/gcc/;c:/mingw/bin/../lib/gcc/mingw32/6.3.0/../../../../mingw32/lib/;c:/mingw/bin/../lib/gcc/mingw32/6.3.0/../../../
COLLECT_GCC_OPTIONS='-o' 'WindowTest.exe' '-static' '-Linclude\glfw-3.3.8.bin.WIN32\lib-vc2022' '-v' '-mtune=generic' '-march=i586'
 c:/mingw/bin/../libexec/gcc/mingw32/6.3.0/collect2.exe -plugin c:/mingw/bin/../libexec/gcc/mingw32/6.3.0/liblto_plugin-0.dll -plugin-opt=c:/mingw/bin/../libexec/gcc/mingw32/6.3.0/lto-wrapper.exe -plugin-opt=-fresolution=C:\Users\owenr\AppData\Local\Temp\ccyUGRgT.res -plugin-opt=-pass-through=-lmingw32 -plugin-opt=-pass-through=-lgcc -plugin-opt=-pass-through=-lgcc_eh -plugin-opt=-pass-through=-lmoldname -plugin-opt=-pass-through=-lmingwex -plugin-opt=-pass-through=-lmsvcrt -plugin-opt=-pass-through=-ladvapi32 -plugin-opt=-pass-through=-lshell32 -plugin-opt=-pass-through=-luser32 -plugin-opt=-pass-through=-lkernel32 -plugin-opt=-pass-through=-lmingw32 -plugin-opt=-pass-through=-lgcc -plugin-opt=-pass-through=-lgcc_eh -plugin-opt=-pass-through=-lmoldname -plugin-opt=-pass-through=-lmingwex -plugin-opt=-pass-through=-lmsvcrt -Bstatic -o WindowTest.exe c:/mingw/bin/../lib/gcc/mingw32/6.3.0/../../../crt2.o c:/mingw/bin/../lib/gcc/mingw32/6.3.0/crtbegin.o -Linclude\glfw-3.3.8.bin.WIN32\lib-vc2022 -Lc:/mingw/bin/../lib/gcc/mingw32/6.3.0 -Lc:/mingw/bin/../lib/gcc -Lc:/mingw/bin/../lib/gcc/mingw32/6.3.0/../../../../mingw32/lib -Lc:/mingw/bin/../lib/gcc/mingw32/6.3.0/../../.. WindowTest.o -lglfw3.lib -lstdc++ -lmingw32 -lgcc -lgcc_eh -lmoldname -lmingwex -lmsvcrt -ladvapi32 -lshell32 -luser32 -lkernel32 -lmingw32 -lgcc -lgcc_eh -lmoldname -lmingwex -lmsvcrt c:/mingw/bin/../lib/gcc/mingw32/6.3.0/crtend.o
c:/mingw/bin/../lib/gcc/mingw32/6.3.0/../../../../mingw32/bin/ld.exe: cannot find -lglfw3.lib
collect2.exe: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

I've tried moving the library file, adding or removing space between the `-l` option and `glfw3.lib`, and many other things. It gives this output every time unless I just don't try to include the library file, in which case I get this error:

```
WindowTest.o:WindowTest.cpp:(.text+0xc): undefined reference to `glfwInit'
collect2.exe: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

Edit:

```
Here's the file system
Main Directory:
    include
        glfw-3.3.8.bin.WIN32
            include
                glw3.h (Header file included in WindowTest.cpp)
            lib-vc2022
                glfw3.lib (Library file I want to include)
    WindowTest.cpp
    MakeFile.bat (Has g++ commands)
```

Comment: What's the name of the library files you are trying to link (I mean its name on the file system) and where is it located (again on the file system). This is a simple case of you telling the linker to look for a library that isn't where you are saying it is. So it should be easy to figure out.

Comment: @john, the post is updated accordingly. However, the problem is that I'm including the library path with the `-L` option, so the linker should already know where to look. In addition, the error code says it's looking for a file called `-lglfw3.lib` instead of just `glfw3.lib`. The linker is interpreting the `-l` option as part of the file name.

Comment: I'd try using forward slashes not backslashes. No space between option and path or file name is also correct (but maybe it works either way). I wouldn't worry about the error message, I don't believe the linker is including the -l in the file name. It's just that option is a bit funky, and the name of the file searched for isn't always exactly the same as the file name given, so I think the error message is just quoting the whole option.

Comment: Didn’t work, still the same error.

Comment: OK then I'd try an absolute path to the library directory e.g. `-LC:/whatever/include/glfw-3.3.8.bin.WIN32/lib-vc2022`. Basically you've just got to go through a process of elimination until you find the issue.

Comment: I found a few things wrong and figured it out. First of all, I was including the file extension, which is redundant and causes problems. Also, the absolute path helps. Of course, with my luck, the library is throwing a whole paragraph of errors, so I'll be switching to SDL2 instead. Thanks!